# Will both electrons in a broken bond move to the conduction band?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electronic-band-theory

Consider a silicon semiconductor at room temperature 300K. A bond constitutes of two electrons. So if a bond is broken will the two electrons in it moves to the conduction band? Or is there a possibility that one can remain in the valence band?
I want to clarify this so as to relate the carrier concentration to the number of bonds broken.
If the number density of silicon is given isn't the number density of bond will be twice that value?

Comment: The picture of silicon 'bonds' with sharing of two specific electrons between two specific silicon atoms, while common in introductory textbooks, does not match up with solid state physics descriptions of electronic band structure of crystals. So, no, you are heading down the wrong path...

Comment: @JonCuster Could you eleborate the details or suggest any resources.